# Toggle Yes / NO with multiple questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 questions in a form, and a few of them have a YES / NO response. I wanted to just be able to toggle the yes and no buttons once the user selected one of them. The issue I am running into is if one of the question is answered, and I answer the next question, it removes the answer from all other questions. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing.

*** Update ***

I got everything working the way I wanted to, thank you all for the help. One thing I have noticed now, the questions with the sub question, when I select the yes or no, the sub question display, but if I click anywhere on the screen, it removes the active class from the question.

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question" id="q-2">
                <p><strong>2.</strong> HAVE YOU HAD SHINGLES?</p>
                <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
                <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no btn-1" data-radio-name="radio">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question" id="q-3">
                <p><strong>3.</strong> HAVE YOU HAD PAIN IN THE AREA OF THE SHINGLES RASH FOR AT LEAST THE LAST 3 MONTHS?</p>
                <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio" value="yes">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio" value="no">No</button>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question sub-question">
                            <p><strong>3A.</strong> IF IT HAS NOT YET BEEN 3 MONTHS, HOW LONG WOULD YOU ESTIMATE THIS PAIN HAS BEEN ONGOING?</p>
                            <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control study-form-control" id="how-many-year" placeholder="How long?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
    $('.yes-no').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('.yes-no').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');


    $(this).val()=='yes'?$(this).closest('div').find('.sub-question').show():$(this).closest('div').find('.sub-question').hide();

});
```

---

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 study-question">
  <p><strong>4.</strong> DO YOU HAVE ANY OTHER CHRONIC  PAIN THAT IS NOT ASSOCIATED WITH YOUR SHINGLES PAIN?</p>
  <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio">No</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
  <p><strong>5.</strong> ARE YOU (CURRENTLY) TAKING MEDICINE TO MANAGE THE PAIN FROM SHINGLES?</p>
  <input name="radio" type='hidden' value="Yes"/>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default yes-no" data-radio-name="radio">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    console.log($(this));
});
```

I just want it to target the current question that the user is trying to answer, not all of them at once.

Comment: Btw, you are calling a click function on a class element "btn-toggle'" but I can't seem to find it anywhere in your html

Comment: If you wish to continue using button controls, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.closest('div')` to target the closest div of the element that triggered the `.change()` event and use `.find()` to target the class.

One function to to deal with all change events for elements with the class of `MyToggle`

This will allow you to run the same function for all questions as shown in the demo below.

> **Update:** Yes/No toggle

**Demo**

```js
$(".MyToggle").click(function() {
    $(this).val()=='yes'?$(this).closest('div').find('.Questions').show():$(this).closest('div').find('.Questions').hide();
});
```

```css
.Questions{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Yes<button class="MyToggle" value="yes">Yes</button> <button class="MyToggle"  value="no">No</button>
    <div class="Questions">Questions?</div>
</div>
<div>
    Yes<input type="radio" name="Q2" class="MyToggle" value="yes"/> No<input type="radio" name="Q2" class="MyToggle"  value="no"/>
    <div class="Questions">Questions?</div>
</div><div>
    Yes<input type="radio" name="Q3" class="MyToggle" value="yes"/> No<input type="radio" name="Q3" class="MyToggle"  value="no"/>
    <div class="Questions">Questions?</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, NewToJs, I took at look at your code and it all makes sense, one question I have is could I modify it so use buttons instead of radio inputs, and if so what property could I check for? Can I use a value on a button?

Comment: @icekomo Yes, just keep the same value and class in the button as you have in the radio and all should work fine. You will also need to swap the `.change()` event for `.click()` I have updated the answer to show you can use radio or buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like NewToJS beat me to the punch with the closest DIV, but instead we use a `.each()` to remove the active class from all buttons in the DIV before adding the active class only to the clicked button.

This example uses buttons instead of radio controls.

```
$('.yes-no').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('.yes-no').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbL8pphr/)

---

And when it comes time to sum up all the answers, you would do it this way:

```
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    var cnt = 0;
    var obj = {};
    $('.btn-group').each(function(){
        cnt++;
        obj[cnt] = $(this).find('.active').text();
    });
    alert( JSON.stringify(obj) );
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbL8pphr/1/)

Comment: I updated the question with an odd thing that is happening when I click anywhere on the screen for certain buttons it removes that active state

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a unique id or class for each button and link a click function for each button like this:

```
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        console.log($(this));
 });

$('.btn-toggle2').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        console.log($(this));
 });

$('.btn-toggle3').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        console.log($(this));
 });

$('.btn-toggle4').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        console.log($(this));
 });
```

Or you can group them together like this if they have a common function:

```
$('.btn-toggle', '.btn-toggle2', '.btn-toggle3', '.btn-toggle4') .click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        console.log($(this));
 });
```

Comment: Btw, you are calling a click function on a class element "btn-toggle'" but I can't seem to find it anywhere in your html

Comment: Andrew, this seems like an excessive amount of code that basically does the same thing over and over again, it might be better to run one function and maybe throw in a switch statement to help simplify things. Just a thought :)