# get child element that gets selected inside div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the radio button that is checked from inside my div

Here is my jquery but c is returning undefined

```js
$('#SpaceType').change(function () {
    var kids = $(this).children();
    $(kids).each(function() {
        var c = $(this).data('id');
    });
});
```

Here is my div

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="SpaceType">
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabelHouse" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="0"> House
                    </label>
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabelApartment" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="1"> Apartment
                    </label>
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabelStudio" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="2"> Studio
                    </label>
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabelOther" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="3"> Other
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/986120/584846

Comment: Why not use a class, then you can use `this` because `this` will = to the element used to trigger the function. Here's something that uses the same method *one function* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969021/jquery-js-how-to-get-menu-name-from-a-href-based-class/28969221#28969221 And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954143/toggle-yes-no-with-multiple-questions/28954314#28954314

Answer (score 1):

Use the :checked selector

```js
$('#SpaceType').change(function () {
  var c  = $(this).find(':checked').attr('id');
  alert(c)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="SpaceType">
  <label id="SpaceTypeLabelHouse" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="0"> House
  </label>
  <label id="SpaceTypeLabelApartment" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="1"> Apartment
  </label>
  <label id="SpaceTypeLabelStudio" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="2"> Studio
  </label>
  <label id="SpaceTypeLabelOther" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="3"> Other
  </label>
</div>
```

In your case you are iterating over the children of `SpaceType` which are the `label` elements and they don't have an `id`, also you are reading the `data` called `id` not the `id` attribute.

Comment: It's not worth writing a new answer, but retrieving the `id` is also trivial in native JavaScript: `c = this.querySelector('input:checked').id;`