# Display Select Option Images On Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to display all select option values on screen. One way I have brainstorm is the following:

```
<select size="4">
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
```

The problem I have with that is that yes all is displayed, but none of them are clicable. I would want that when one of them is clicked, it redirects the user to another url. I would also want each option to be a banner.

The reason I am doing that is because I have already 10 images known as 10 city, and I want to record the city selection of the user so that I am able to populate the right neighborhood to them.

Update:

Below are the links with their respective images:

```
<a href="createEventRestaurant.html""><img id="selectNeighbourhood1" src="content/San-Francisco/berkeleyCampanile.jpg"></a>


<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img  id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/castro.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img  id="selectNeighbourhood"src="content/San-Francisco/dogpatch-tasting-room.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood"src="content/San-Francisco/FD1.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Fishermans-Wharf.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Golden-Gate-Park.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Hayes-Valley.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Marina.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Mid-market.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Mission-district.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Noe-Valley.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Pacific-heights.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Russian-hill.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Soma.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Stanford-university.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Sunset-district.jpg"></a>

<a href="createEventRestaurant.html" target="_self"><img id="selectNeighbourhood" src="content/San-Francisco/Tenderloin.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: Where are the images? And what is clickable? Where are the urls you want to redirect the user to? You need to display all relevant source code and information for us to help you. Here we have nothing but a **I want** list and an empty select element....

Comment: I think in that case a `select` won't be your best choice, why can't you use a `ul li` combination to create a visual effect you want

Comment: Thanks for your responses. To clarify I have added an update under my initial post displaying the image with the link associated with it. The main reason I want to use select, is that using its ID i can identify which item was clicked

Comment: First problem I see, you have the same `id` for multiple elements. An `id` is to identify a specific element (One of) If you want to assign something assign them into a group use `class`. Change the elements to a class and you can use jQuery to get the element in one function

Comment: so i can replace all those id, mainly for stylistic as a class what would be the next step>

Comment: id must be unique. If you want a similar style on multiple things, use a class, not an id

Comment: I have two answers, if you read them you should be able to fix your problem. First one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954143/toggle-yes-no-with-multiple-questions/28954314#28954314 and this one gives more detail on how `this.` works within the function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969021/jquery-js-how-to-get-menu-name-from-a-href-based-class/28969221#28969221

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This convo has help me realize that the better strategy could be to use json data (question is quite complex). I know its a bit off but I would appreciate and credit help. below is the jsfiiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UTp4T/42/ as of now I would like set the image width to 100%, for some reason i can only set it by pix, and also add a url to it. so the images link to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Let this be your html

```
<select id="select" size="4">
<option value="http://www.google.com">option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
</select>
```

This be your javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById('select')

select.addEventListener('click', go, false);

function go (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = e.target.value;
    window.location.href= url;
}
```

This will allow you to get redirected when clicked on the option

Answer (score 0):

I have something that might work for you. *It shows how you can create your own "drop-down", get what the user clicked, and populate a DIV with the appropriate image.* I hope that's what you're trying to do.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6s2gsm4j/1/)

The "dropdown menu" is created by DIVs. There's an outer DIV, `#top`, and a number of child divs, of class `.menuitem`. The `menuitem` divs are contained in a wrapper div called `#menu`, which can slide up/down, giving the appearance of a `<select>` control.

When you click on a city name, the jQuery code reads the ID of the clicked-on selection, and uses that information to populate a `picFrame` div. If I was to re-write this, I would do it like this:

[revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s2gsm4j/2/) - *instead of inserting the entire img tag, it only updates the `src=` attribute of the existing img tag*

Note that jsFiddle has some issues... it's not a perfect environment. For one, the #head div ("Choose a city") is transparent. It shouldn't be. Also, the city names should be centered -- but jsFiddle does not give preference to an ID (in css, id is supposed to "win" over class)

Anyway, it's a start. Hope it helps.

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="head" class="clickable">Choose a City</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="menuitem clickable" id="m1">
            <div class="thepic" id="pic1"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/50" /></div>
            <div class="moveleft">Cupertino</div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem clickable" id="m2">
            <div class="thepic" id="pic2"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/51" /></div>
            <div class="moveleft">San Francisco</div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem clickable" id="m3">
            <div class="thepic" id="pic3"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/49" /></div>
            <div class="moveleft">Silicon Valley</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="picframe"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var themap;
$('#head').click(function(){
    $('#menu').animate({
        top: 0
    },800);
});
$('.menuitem').click(function(){
    var loc = this.id;
    if (loc=='m1'){
        themap = '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" />';
    }else if (loc=='m2'){
        themap = '<img src="http://placekitten.com/149/151" />';
    }else{
        themap = '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/151/149" />';
    }

    $('#menu').animate({
        top: '-300px'
    },1000);
    $('#picframe').html(themap);
});
```

CSS:

```
img{opacity:.3;}
.clickable{cursor:pointer;}
#head{height:35px;width:304px;font-size:2em;text-align:center;z-index:2;background:white;}
#menu{position:relative;top:-300px;}
.menuitem{position:relative;width:304px;height:54px;margin:5px 0;}
.thepic{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.moveleft{position:relative;top:10px;left:0;background:transparent;font-size:2em;color:blue;}
#pic1{width:130px;margin:0 auto;}
#pic2{width:200px;margin:0 auto;}
#pic3{width:230px;margin:0 auto;}
#picframe{height:150px;width:150px;border:1px solid grey;}
```

---

Reference (re css precedence):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/